# exclusion of Sales tax

Tags: cartthrob, shopping-cart

I am new to EE.WE are using cartThrob .Now we have set up 13% sales tax globally. The twist comes now.When a person buys 6 or more items , there should be no tax charged for One region(Eg Ontario) . Is there any way to set this rule in EE backend? Does cartThrob provide this kind of functionality.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if CT's built-in tax plugins won't do this you can build your own very easily: http://cartthrob.com/docs/developers/tax_plugins/index.html